# php code to make a fieldset invisible in html page

Tags: php

I have a fieldset in the html page.I need the field set to be invisible during a specific radio button click.

$cat is the radiobutton name,Dessert is the value.This radio button is inside the field set

The following code does not work.

How to do this through php code.I don't need to be done with javascript or jquery.

Here is the Code :

```
<?
if((!empty($cat) && $cat==="Dessert"))
 {
  echo "<fieldset id='typeradio' hidden='hidden'>";
  echo"success";
 } >?
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: you can't make php directly execute on a client-side event because php is executed server-side. You *must* use at least *some* javascript (ajax) for this. e.g. use ajax to send a request to php to evaluate and return a response - and then use js to do the update. IOW you *can't* do this solely with php

Comment: The only way it wouldn't work is if `$cat != "Dessert"`. Why isn't `$cat === "Dessert"`? Is this an `AJAX` callback? Is your `$cat` variable being properly populated?

Comment: $cat is your radio button name..you can not access it in php like the way you said. either post the form or make an ajax call to set the value

Answer (score 0):

Try  This

It will only work if you post back your page and set the `$cat` property there otherwise you will have to do it via `Jquery` or `JavaScript` or `ajax request`. By post back i mean full page reload and server will do all checks and `apache` server will generate Html for this `if` condition

```
<?
if((!empty($cat) && $cat==="Dessert"))
{
 echo "<fieldset id='typeradio' style='display:none'>";
 echo"success";
 } >?
```

Comment: how does that solves the problem. How you are accessing the value in php?

Comment: @techG sometime we actually do page post back and set values there on server and then via php check it, This will set the values only if page is posted back properly to the server and there he/she set the values and php runs this page then it will generate the html like this one `<fieldset id="typeradio" style="display:none;">`

Comment: You are assuming things. The OP did not make any such statement of posting to server. I will really suggest you edit your answer with the conditions you assumed. Otherwise it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it if you don't want it to work

```
<fieldset id="typeradio" disabled>
```

or hide it using CSS

```
<fieldset id="typeradio" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this example.php

<?
if(isset($_POST['opt'])){
$cat=$_POST['opt'];
if($cat==="Dessert")
 {
echo "<form name="frm" action='example.php' method="post"><fieldset id='typeradio' hidden='hidden'><input type='radio' name='opt' value="Dessert" onclick="this.form.submit();"></fieldset></form>";

  echo"success";
 } 

}
else
{
echo "<form name="frm" action='example.php' method="post"><fieldset id='typeradio' ><input type='radio' name='opt' value="Dessert" onclick="this.form.submit();"></fieldset></form>";
}

>?
```

Comment: Can you describe your answer?

Comment: when i give the form name in double quotes,i get an error saying unexpected"frm".I have a seperate html page and php page,How can i resolve.

Comment: i need the field set to get disappear before the submit button click ie after the radio button click..

Answer (score 0):

```
//there was some quotes mistakes in previous code try this

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['opt'])){
$cat=$_POST['opt'];
if($cat==="Dessert")
 {
echo "<form name='frm' action='example.php' method='post'><fieldset id='typeradio' hidden='hidden'><input type='radio' name='opt' value='Dessert' onclick='this.form.submit();'></fieldset></form>";

  echo"success";
 } 

}
else
{
echo "<form name='frm' action='' method='post'><fieldset id='typeradio' ><input type='radio' name='opt' value='Dessert' onclick='this.form.submit();'></fieldset></form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the submit(). where to give that one?

Comment: on click of radio button submit function of form will call